# How can Mrs Frisby read in "Racso and the Rats of NIMH"?

Tags: rats-of-nimh

In the first novel ["Mrs. Frisby and the Rats of NIMH"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mrs._Frisby_and_the_Rats_of_NIMH) Mrs. Frisby has not been treated with the drug that allowed her husband to read, nor has she had schooling, nor is she even aware her husbands ability to read until well into the novel.

In the second book ["Racso and the Rats of NIMH"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racso_and_the_Rats_of_NIMH) (written by O'Brien's daughter, Jane Leslie Conly,) Mrs. Frisby has several notes delivered to her and she is able to read them.  How is this possible?

Comment: It seems like a classic case of Anthropomorphic Shift:  http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AnthropomorphicShift

Comment: I can give you an answer from the movie, but I don't understand how we can answer your question without it being a spoiler...

Comment: @miltonaut I just finished reading "Racso and the Rats of NIMH" and did not see it addressed, I have not seen any of the movies.  It would only be a spoiler if, it is a critical plot point in the next of the series. If so you can hide it with [spoiler markup](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1856/) if it is not a key plot point and described in a companion work (*movie, author quote, etc*) at the same point in the story, which brings up the question, you can answer without risk of being a spoiler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mrs. Frisby meets Nicodemus, the leader of the rats at around 49 minutes into the movie The Secret of NIMH. Nicodemus to tells her to read from a book. She says:

> I *can* read--a little. Jonathan taught me. The children are better at it than I am.

She then reads haltingly from the book Nicodemus indicated.

How can she read? **She was taught.**

---

The version I was watching doesn't have subtitles, so I don't have a screenshot.

Comment: In the novel, there is a similar scene — Mrs. Frisby is left to wait for someone in the rats' library, and is able to read the titles of some books and a chalkboard on the wall.

Answer (score 3):

As I recall, the point was made that, while she could not learn from scratch in the way that the NIMH rats can, she was perfectly capable of being taught. The implication is that any intelligent rat can be taught to read; the enhancements of the NIMH rats merely meant that they could learn without being taught.